# How to compile c++ library to be used in AWS Lambda?

Tags: java, c++, compilation, aws-lambda

I haven't tried it yet, but I know you can supposedly run AWS Lambda functions in Java and reference C++ libraries from them.
How do you compile the C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was struggling to do exactly what you ask only a few days ago when I've stumbled upon this article:
http://www.glfrc.com/2018/01/19/aws-lambda-with-java-and-native-code/

You basically have 2 options:

- on an Amazon Linux EC2 machine.
- on any machine running docker by using the Amazon Linux docker image.

The article explains the second procedure, which is the one I've gone for as well. The first one should be similar. You start an EC2, install the same packages, upload your code and compile.

Comment: Amazon Linux is based on CentOS right? Can't I compile on it?

Comment: You could try and let me know. As far as I know Amazon Linux was originally forked from RH/CentOS, but it has diverged a lot since then. I doubt it'd work, and even if it does, I wouldn't rely on such a solution for any actual software project.