# Possible approaches to in Browser code execution

Tags: browser, aws-lambda, webassembly

I am about to look into developing an in browser coding app for high school students that matches the modern computer science curriculum . The idea would be to avoid schools or students having to download software etc to learn the basic operations in C C++ Java and Python, as these are the permitted languages students can study .  Ideally this would all be done in browser to make the offering as accessible as possible to schools.

My question is around the approach to research . Could we assembly be the way to go or would running functions on aws  lamda be the way to go ? I know there are in browser tools for each language but not across them all

Answer (score 0):

This question is very broad, and the answer all depends on the level of investment you want to make.

1. Using server-side technologies would be an easier option, as they are quite mature. AWS Lambda supports Java & Python, however C & C++ are an issue:

[How to compile c++ library to be used in AWS Lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48722922/how-to-compile-c-library-to-be-used-in-aws-lambda)

2. Doing this all client-side would be more challenging. WebAssembly is a very new technology with good support for C & C++ via Emscripten, but poor / experimental support for Java & Python.

Personally I wouldn't use either option. I'd go for EC2, creating a machine image that had Java, Python, C & C++ set up to compile and execute code.

Creating an interactive programming environment (with debugging, syntax highlighting), is more challenging still.